# what are the user information that I am able to collect when they visit my website

Tags: javascript, php, apache

currently I have a few in mind. correct me if I am wrong.
php

```
$_SERVER[REQUEST_TIME]:the time a visitor visits my webpage
$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]:the webpage where my visitor comes from
$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]:my visitor's web browser
$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]:my visitors ip address
$_SERVER[SCRIPT_FILENAME]:the page my visitor is seeing
```

javascript

```
window.screen.width:width of my client's screen
window.screen.height:height of my client's screen
```

please help me find more. also I prefer to collect the real data, I know it is possible for a client to fake some of these server variables.

Comment: look output for `<? phpinfo(); ?>` . Look at Chrome -> Developer Tools -> Network -> Headers rab for any request. Look at Google Analytics (but some data they collected are statistics)

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Relying on the $_SERVER special array isn't a valid security mechanism. If you are trying to "profile" visits to your site, you need to be looking at the entire session. Its very difficult to detect robotic usage, because its very easy to simulate real usage.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing on the internet is real and you can't rely on the *trustfulness* of the information from your above code.

- The `$_SERVER[HTTP_REFERER]` can be spoofed.
- The `$_SERVER[REMOTE_ADDR]` becomes invalid when the user is behind a proxy.
- The `$_SERVER[HTTP_USER_AGENT]` can also be modified using `User Agent Switcher`

These are just shallow information and you cannot fully rely on them.

Since you wanted more parameters, you can have a look here at [`$_SERVER`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) variables.

**`FYI :`**

```
<?php
print_r($_SERVER); //"prints" all server variables.
```